# Correct way to avoid errors on empty properties

Tags: javascript

I had it mind that this was the correct way to avoid errors when testing properties which might not exist, but it's very clunky, and doesn't do the job properly anyway! What's a better way of returning 'num' if the relevant 'name' is in the array?

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push ( {'name': 'ann', 'num':5} );
myArray.push ( {'name': 'bob', 'num':6} );

var num = (myArray.map(function(s) { return s.name }).indexOf('charles')) ? myArray[myArray.map(function(s) { return s.name }).indexOf('charles')].num : 0;

console.log(num);
```

Comment: You should check if myArray.map(function(s) { return s.name }).indexOf('charles')) !== -1, indexOf returns -1 as true

Comment: running map twice is really inefficient.

Comment: Are there duplicate names? Will ann be num 5 and num 10 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find()`:

```
var obj = myArray.find(function(entry) { return entry.name === "charles"; });
return obj ? obj.num : undefined;
```

The `.find()` function takes a predicate function as its arguments and returns the first entry in the array that succeeds the test. This code checks that `.find()` returns one of the array entries, and returns the `.num` property if an entry was found.